# What is the difference between Adobe TypeKit & Adobe Edge Web Fonts?

Tags: typography, typekit

I has originally planend to use Myriad Pro on my website, but found this was a paid font from Adobe Typekit.

I have settled for Droid Sans which is pretty similar, I was going to use Google Font plugin on Wordpress. But I see Adobe Edge Web Fonts have Droid Sans and a stack of other fonts for what appears to be free? Is this right?

Comment: Google Fonts is also free, and it's not a plugin. If all you need is Droid I'd use Google, personally - you can @import the font directly into your CSS and avoid the JavaScript overhead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct. Adobe Edge Web Fonts is a free service from Adobe, an "open"-like equivalent for Typekit. It uses the same structure and works the same way, but it's free. However, fonts available there are usually lower quality or very well-known open license type families.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that basically Adobe Edge Web Fonts is a free version of TypeKit. TypeKit is a fantastic typeface solution for the web. I use it on many sites. The service does not cost much and has an incredibly selection.

Some may find it odd that I will start a new web project with the typeface. I want to find a typeface or pair typefaces with that business's personality. Since type can say so much, it's important I get that right, so I do it first.

I imagine the selection of free typefaces on Adobe Edge Web Fonts will be nice, but not a robust as the paid versions at TypeKit. For me, I want quality. I gladly pay for TypeKit. I feel good knowing I have am giving back to the typefaces founders for their hard work.

You can read more about [TypeKit and Adobe Edge Web Fonts on their official site](https://edgewebfonts.adobe.com/help#typekit-and-edge-web-fonts).